# Call cells into text boxes in ms-access

Tags: ms-access, textbox

I have multiple company's with different web sites and contact numbers. 
I want to have a test box say something like this.

"Call us at =[comp_number] ! We are open ....blah, or Visit our web site =[website] to signup for our automatic payment options. "

I am not having any luck finding any information on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

="Call us at " & [comp_number] & "!"